# Installing Tomcat 6 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux, centos, tomcat, yum

I have a CentOS 6.3 server with cPanel. I want to install tomcat 6 (not 5.5 that cPanel supports).

When I tried :

`yum -y install tomcat6 tomcat6-webapps tomcat6-admin-webapps`

I get the error: [(View Full)](http://paste.laravel.com/3cH)

```
Error: Package: jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.1-11.4.el6.noarch (base)
Requires: apache-tomcat-apis
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 6 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(bandmin.conf)
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(bmversion.pl)
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(services.conf)
exim-4.77-1.i386 has missing requires of perl(SafeFile)
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
```

How should I proceed to install Tomcat 6? Thanks!

---

**`yum repolist`**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * extras: centos.corenetworks.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
base                                                                                                                            | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                          | 3.0 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                         | 3.5 kB     00:00
repo id                                                       repo name                                                                        status
base                                                          CentOS-6 - Base                                                                  4,701+75
extras                                                        CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                       4
rpmforge                                                      RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                                      4,372+86
updates                                                       CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                 341+28
repolist: 9,418
```

---

**`grep exclude /etc/yum.conf`**

`exclude=apache* bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby* spamassassin* squirrelmail*`

Comment: `yum repolist` and show us some lines above that error?

Comment: @quanta Updated post. Full error msg: paste.laravel.com/3cH

Comment: `grep exclude /etc/yum.conf`?

Comment: @quanta updated post. `apache*` seems suspicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with cPanel, but it looks like that cPanel configures `yum` to exclude `apache*` updates to protect it's own packages.

```
Error: Package: jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.1-11.4.el6.noarch (base)
Requires: apache-tomcat-apis
```

`jakarta-taglibs-standard` requires `apache-tomcat-apis` but it cannot be installed due to the above configuration in `/etc/yum.conf`. So, try this:

```
yum --disableexcludes=main install tomcat6 tomcat6-webapps tomcat6-admin-webapps
```

Comment: That's a bit obnoxious of them.